# How can I store elements of a .csv file into a 2-dimensional vector in C++?

Tags: c++, csv, multidimensional-array, vector

I am trying to store the contents of a .csv file into a 2D vector.

I am able to store the .csv file into a single dimension vector, which I use in my class in a "read" function to count the row and column size. Below is the current code I have where I get an error at the line:

```
getline(ss,column.at(i),',');
```

The error says vector subscript is out of range if I use bracket indices and out of range at memory location when using ___.at().

My read function runs and I am able to get the correct row and column size as well as store the contents of the file into the vector.

```
class database {
public:
int row = 0;
int col = 0;
vector <vector<string>> dataset;
void read(string filename) {
    vector<string> data;
    ifstream file{ filename };
    string line;
    while (file)
    {
        getline(file, line);
        string newline;
        newline = line + "\n";
        data.push_back(newline);
    }
    col = count(data.at(0).begin(), data.at(0).end(), ',') + 1;
    row = data.size() - 1;
}
void write(string filename){
    ifstream file{ filename };
    string line;
    while (getline(file, line))
    {
        stringstream ss(line);
        vector<string> column;
        for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
        {
            getline(ss, column.at(i), ',');
        }
        cout << column.size();
        dataset.push_back(column);
    }       
}
};
```

I am trying to use cout << column.size() to see if it matches the size of my data vector, which is the single dimension vector containing all the contents of the .csv file.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/how-can-i-read-and-parse-csv-files-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a "more modern" C++ approach.

And still all people are linking to How can I read and parse CSV files in C++?, the questions is from 2009 and now over 10 years old. Most answers are also old and very complicated. So, maybe its time for a change.

In modern C++ you have algorithms that iterate over ranges. You will often see something like "someAlgoritm(container.begin(), container.end(), someLambda)". The idea is that we iterate over some similar elements.

In your case we iterate over tokens in your input string, and create substrings. This is called tokenizing.

And for exactly that purpose, we have the `std::sregex_token_iterator`. And because we have something that has been defined for such purpose, we should use it.

This thing is an iterator. For iterating over a string, hence sregex. The begin part defines, on what range of input we shall operate, then there is a `std::regex` for what should be matched / or what should not be matched in the input string. The type of matching strategy is given with last parameter.

- 1 --> give me the stuff that I defined in the regex and
- -1 --> give me that what is NOT matched based on the regex.

So, now that we understand the iterator, we can std::copy the tokens from the iterator to our target, a `std::vector` of `std::string`. And since we do not know, how may columns we have, we will use the `std::back_inserter` as a target. This will add all tokens that we get from the `std::sregex_token_iterator` and append it ot our `std::vector<std::string>>`. It does'nt matter how many columns we have.

Good. Such a statement could look like

```
std::copy(                          // We want to copy something
    std::sregex_token_iterator      // The iterator begin, the sregex_token_iterator. Give back first token
    (
        line.begin(),               // Evaluate the input string from the beginning
        line.end(),                 // to the end
        re,                         // Add match a comma
        -1                          // But give me back not the comma but everything else 
    ),
    std::sregex_token_iterator(),   // iterator end for sregex_token_iterator, last token + 1
    std::back_inserter(cp.columns)  // Append everything to the target container
);
```

Now we can understand, how this copy operation works.

Next step. We want to read from a file. The file conatins also some kind of same data. The same data are rows.

And as for above, we can iterate of similar data. If it is the file input or whatever. For this purpose C++ has the `std::istream_iterator`. This is a template and as a template parameter it gets the type of data that it should read and, as a constructor parameter it gets a reference to an input stream. It doesnt't matter, if the input stream is a `std::cin`, or a `std::ifstream` or a `std::istringstream`. The behaviour is identical for all kinds of streams.

And since we do not have files an SO, I use (in the below example) a `std::istringstream` to store the input csv file. But of course you can open a file, by defining a `std::ifstream testCsv(filename)`. No problem.

And with `std::istream_iterator`, we iterate over the input and read similar data. In our case one problem is that we want to iterate over special data and not over some build in data type.

To solve this, we define a Proxy class, which does the internal work for us (we do not want to know how, that should be encapsulated in the proxy). In the proxy we overwrite the type cast operator, to get the result to our expected type for the `std::istream_iterator`.

And the last important step. A `std::vector` has a range constructor. It has also a lot of other constructors that we can use in the definition of a variable of type `std::vector`. But for our purposes this constructor fits best.

So we define a variable csv and use its range constructor and give it a begin of a range and an end of a range. And, in our specific example, we use the begin and end iterator of `std::istream_iterator`.

If we combine all the above, reading the complete CSV file is a *one-liner*, it is the definition of a variable with calling its constructor.

Please see the resulting code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <algorithm>

std::istringstream testCsv{ R"(0, 6/19/2019, 16:41:33, 33.972622, -117.323482, 24.25, 23.5, 23.25, 24.75, 25.5, 24.25, 25.25, 25.5, 24.5, 24, 24, 24.25, 25.5, 25.75, 25.25, 25, 24.5, 24.75, 24.75, 24.75, 25.25, 24.5, 24.5, 25.5, 23.75, 24.25, 24.75, 24, 24.25, 24, 24.5, 25, 24.25, 24, 24.25, 24.25, 24, 24.25, 24.5, 25.5, 24, 25, 24.5, 24.75, 24.5, 24.75, 24.75, 25.5, 24.5, 24.25, 24.25, 25.25, 25.25, 23.5, 25, 24.75, 24.5, 24.75, 25.5, 24.25, 23.5, 24, 25.25, 25, 605, 597, 515, 514, 509, 511, 508
0, 6/19/ 2019, 16:41:42, 33.972648, -117.323492, 24, 23.5, 23.75, 24.25, 25.5, 25.5, 25.25, 25.25, 25, 24.5, 24.25, 24.5, 25, 25.5, 25.5, 25.75, 24.25, 23.5, 24.75, 24.5, 24.25, 24.25, 24.5, 25.5, 24, 23.75, 24.5, 24, 24.25, 24, 24.75, 25.25, 25, 23.75, 24.75, 25.5, 25.5, 26, 24.75, 25.25, 24.5, 25, 25.25, 25.25, 26, 24.75, 24.5, 25.5, 24.5, 24.5, 25, 24.75, 24.25, 24.25, 25, 25, 24, 24, 24.75, 25, 23.25, 24.25, 25.5, 25.5, 609, 595, 1229, 1227, 1200, 1196, 1171
0, 6/19/2019, 16:41:49, 33.972643, -117.323479, 24.5, 23, 22.75, 24, 25.25, 25.5, 25, 26, 24.75, 24, 24, 24.75, 24.75, 25.25, 25.5, 26, 24.75, 24, 24.75, 25, 24.25, 24.25, 24.75, 26, 24.5, 23.5, 24.5, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25.75, 24.75, 23.25, 24.5, 24.5, 24.5, 25, 25.25, 25.25, 24, 25, 24.5, 25.25, 25.25, 25.25, 25.25, 25.5, 24.5, 24, 25.25, 25, 25, 24.25, 25, 25.25, 24.25, 24, 24.75, 25.25, 23.75, 24.25, 25, 25.5, 621, 601, 706, 725, 703, 707, 704
1, 6/19/2019, 16:41:55, 33.972631, -117.323483, 24.25, 23.75, 23.25, 24, 25.25, 25.25, 25.5, 26, 24.5, 24.25, 23.75, 24.5, 24.75, 25.5, 26, 25.5, 25, 23.75, 24.75, 24.75, 25.25, 25.25, 25, 26.25, 24.5, 23.5, 24.25, 25, 24.25, 24.25, 24.75, 25.75, 24.75, 23.75, 24.25, 24.25, 24.25, 24.5, 25.25, 25.25, 24.5, 24.5, 24.75, 25, 25.25, 26, 25.5, 25.25, 24.5, 24, 24.75, 25, 25, 25.25, 25.5, 25.5, 24.25, 25, 25, 25.75, 24.25, 24.5, 25.25, 25.5, 613, 602, 721, 720, 699, 704, 696
)" };


// Define Alias for Easier Reading
using Columns = std::vector<std::string>;
using CSV = std::vector<Columns>;


// Proxy for the input Iterator
struct ColumnProxy {    
    // Overload extractor. Read a complete line
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, ColumnProxy& cp) {

        // Read a line
        std::string line; cp.columns.clear();
        std::getline(is, line);

        // The delimiter
        const std::regex re(",");

        // Split values and copy into resulting vector
        std::copy(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), re, -1),
            std::sregex_token_iterator(),
            std::back_inserter(cp.columns));
        return is;
    }

    // Type cast operator overload.  Cast the type 'Columns' to std::vector<std::string>
    operator std::vector<std::string>() const { return columns; }
protected:
    // Temporary to hold the read vector
    Columns columns{};
};


int main()
{
    // Define variable CSV with its range constructor. Read complete CSV in this statement
    CSV csv{ std::istream_iterator<ColumnProxy>(testCsv), std::istream_iterator<ColumnProxy>() };

    // Print result. Go through all lines and then copy line elements to std::cout
    std::for_each(csv.begin(), csv.end(), [](Columns& c) {
        std::copy(c.begin(), c.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " ")); std::cout << "\n";   });
}
```

I hope the explanation was detailed enough to give you an idea, what you can do with modern C++